# Github folder not being committed fully

Tags: github

Sadly I've been at it for 3 hours trying to commit my assignment which is a single folder... This is my private github repo

[image]

I can't drag the folder since it's limited at 100 files apparently there's like 4000 in my folder?

What I've done is:

```
$ git clone githuburl

(i now dragged my assignment folder to this repo in my own pc)


$ git add assignmentfolder (pages)

$ git commit -m "first commit"

$ git push origin master
```

And as you can see it straight up ignored every single file and just committed the folder name?

Comment: Try 'git add --all'

Comment: This will work in this case, but it is a bad way of doing it. In the future while working with larger repos you will end up with junk in your commit history. Very hard to clean.

Comment: $ git add --all

$ git commit -m "commit 2"
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean. Didn't work either rip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the proper way to do this is:

```
git clone githuburl
cd githubfoldername
```

then move all your files there
add a `.gitignore` file there and exclude `node_modules` and everything else that has to do with caching and external packages because you don't need them in your repo. Everyone who is going to use your code will be able to install the packages as you did. Just make sure you include the:

- `packages.json` if you used `npm`
- or `yarn.lock` if you used yarn

Then you can safely

```
git add --all
git commit -m "your message"
```

This way you will avoid adding useless files to your repo as **@Dmitri Sandler** said and you will be able to push everything easily

Comment: The `git add --all` and `git commit -a` are redundant. If you ran `add` you can omit `-a` parameter and vice versa.

Comment: Correct! Fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should think about files not folders. Try to use wildcard in the path:

```
git add <folder>/*
```

It is a good idea to use `git status` to see what files were staged for commit prior to committing them.

Comment: $ git add pages/*
fatal: Pathspec 'pages/node_modules' is in submodule 'pages'

Comment: This means you have one repo inside another one. You can add that folder to .gitignore to avoid trying to commit it in the future.